# having issue on Accessing Ajax Post data on PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I am having some issue on accessing Ajax Post data on server side. I have

```
var data = {
            ox:'A', 
            oy:'B', 
            dx:'C',
            dy:'D',
            method:null
        };
```

I have a jQuery event hamdler like

```
        $("#route").on("click", function(){
            var request = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "assets/app.php",
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "JSON",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

            request.done(function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
            });
            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
              console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            }); 
        });
```

I am able to send the data correctly as it is logging out at `beforeSend`

> {ox: A, oy: B, dx: C, dy: D, method: null}

On PHP side I have

```
$method = $_POST['method'];
$ox = $_POST['ox'];
$oy = $_POST['oy'];
$dx = $_POST['dx'];
$dy = $_POST['dy'];
```

now only accessing to one of the `$_POST[]` data is working like `echo $ox;` but when I try to access all `$_POST[]` data like

```
 echo $ox;
 echo $dy;

 $startPoint = array($ox, $oy);
 $endPoint = array($dx, $dy);
```

I am getting `Request failed: parsererror`  error on `.fail()`

Comment: Do a var_dump on $_POST and update here te help.

Comment: You are requesting JSON in return, and echoing out NON-JSON in php... this will cause a failure in ajax. Change your php echos to echo'ing only a `json_encode();` type result, and that ajax error should go away. As in `echo json_encode($_POST); exit;` to see what came into php.

Comment: Also to help you debug in the future, is to always look at the 'raw' send and receive data under the 'network' tab in the browser dev tools. That way you can visually see that what you got in return, was not proper json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>   Type: String
>   The type of data that you're **expecting back** from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are:

So, your response isn't a valid JSON.

What you can do is to create an array, like you are doing:

```
 $startPoint = array($ox, $oy);
 $endPoint = array($dx, $dy);
```

Then encode into json and `echo` it

```
echo json_encode(['startPoint' => $startPoint, 'endPoint' => $endPoint]);
```

On the frontend (javascript) you will get and JSON like

```
{
    'startPoint' : ['ox','oy'],
    'endPoint' : ['dx','dy'],
}
```

the values of ox, oy, dx and dy, of course, will be the values sent before.